# Is there a way we can call a java class and execute using google cloud workflows?

Tags: google-workflows

I am working to encode a file using  base64 encoding. However I have to do it in cloud workflows. I am new to workflows, can someone guide me on how to do.

Answer (score 2):

While Workflows can [encode](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/base64/encode) small amounts of data such as the arguments to an API, larger processing operations like encoding a full file should be done in a service called from a workflow step. Place your Java code in a Cloud Function or Cloud Run service and [call it in a workflow step](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/calling-run-functions).